# Por que sale el error missing comma en Oracle al ejecutar query?

Tags: java, oracle, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta que inserta un formato de fecha, pero al ejecutarla me manda el siguiente error en Oracle, en la linea donde esta esto '**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z''**
alguien sabe que me falta?

```html
INSERT INTO ESQUEMA.CONFIG
(ID_CONFIG, TIYPE, KEYTYPE,  JTYPE,

    DESCRIPCION, ID_REG,                                                                            

    VALIDACION, BLN_REINICIO, FORMATO)
VALUES

((SELECT MAX(ID_CONF)+1 FROM ESQUEMA.CONFIG), 'MC', 'FORMAT', 'java.lang.string',

  'FORMATO FECHA', '277885b1-1328-4365-abe6-9bfc7ff222e3',

  null, 0, 'NW');



 INSERT INTO ESQUEMA.VALORES
(ID_VALOR,ID_CONFIG,

    ID_CHANNEL,ID_CHANNEL_APP,

    VALOR, BLN_REINICIO, ID_REG)

    VALUES

    (ESQUEMA.SEQ_VALORES.NEXTVAL,(SELECT ID_CONFIG FROM ESQUEMA.CONFIG WHERE TYPE = 'MC' AND KEYTYPE = 'FORMAT' AND FORMATO = 'NW'),

     (SELECT ID_CHANNEL FROM ESQUEMA.CHANNEL WHERE CLAVE = 'ABC'),
     (SELECT ID_CHANNEL_APP FROM ESQUEMA.CHANNEL_APP WHERE ID_APP = 
     (SELECT ID_CAP_APP FROM ESQUEMA.CAP_APP WHERE VAR_CLAVE_APP = 'ABC') AND VAR_DESCRIP = 'ABC_NW'), 
    'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'',
     0, '2e18a546-eb94-49ad-b894-94fd85de71e6');

     

commit;
```

Error en la línea de comandos : 26 Columna : 37

Informe de error -

Error SQL: ORA-00917: falta la coma

917. 00000 -  "missing comma"

Comment: Te falta escapar las comillas simple para `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` quedaría como `yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSS''Z''` (dos comillas simples seguidas escapan la comilla simple)